# Python- How to place two buttons left-right and next to each other in the middle of screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

First, I read the related discussion:
[How can I put 2 buttons next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261191/how-can-i-put-2-buttons-next-to-each-other).

However, I still confused about it. My codes:

#Import the required Libraries

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random


win = Tk()
win.geometry("750x250")

def clear():
   entry.delete(0,END)
def display_num():
   for i in range(1):
      entry.insert(0, random.randint(5,20))

entry= Entry(win, width= 40)
entry.pack()
button1= ttk.Button(win, text= "Print", command=display_num)
button1.pack(side= LEFT)
button2= ttk.Button(win, text= "Clear", command= clear)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)

win.mainloop()
```

Now I got

[image]

I want two buttons in the middle of screen just below the Entry (white box).
How to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: You can use layout managers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make another `tk.Frame` which is arranged horizontally and pack it below; for example:

```
entry= Entry(win, width= 40)
entry.pack()
buttons = ttk.Frame(win)
buttons.pack(pady = 5)
button1= ttk.Button(buttons, text= "Print", command=display_num)
button1.pack(side = LEFT)
button2= ttk.Button(buttons, text= "Clear", command= clear)
button2.pack()
```

[image: pack with padding]

Alternatively you can use the [`grid` layout manager](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm).

```
entry= Entry(win, width= 40)
entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
button1= ttk.Button(win, text= "Print", command=display_num)
button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button2= ttk.Button(win, text= "Clear", command= clear)
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with pack means working with parcels, therefore Imagine a rectangle around your widgets while we discuss further more. By default your values look like this:

```
widget.pack(side='top',expand=False,fill=None,anchor='center')
```

To get your widget in the spot you like you will need to define it by these parameters. the side determinates in which direction it should be *added* to. Expand tells your parcel to consume extra space in the master. fill tells your widget to strech out in its parcel in *x* or *y* or *both* direction. you can also choose to anchor your widget in your parcel in *east*,*west*,*north*,*south* or a combination of it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random


win = Tk()
win.geometry("750x250")

def clear():
   entry.delete(0,END)
def display_num():
   for i in range(1):
      entry.insert(0, random.randint(5,20))

entry= Entry(win)
entry.pack(fill='x')
button1= ttk.Button(win, text= "Print", command=display_num)
button1.pack(side= LEFT,expand=1,anchor='ne')
button2= ttk.Button(win, text= "Clear", command= clear)
button2.pack(side=LEFT,expand=1,anchor='nw')

win.mainloop()
```

To learn more about orginizing widgets and the geometry management of tkinter, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506).